# Editing the contents of a ListBox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a ListBox with various rows of data (items that someone is buying, basically), and when the user clicks on a row it populates a textbox on the side with the quantity of how many of that thing he's buying.  For example, one row might be "Pencils, $5, 3" and clicking the row makes "3" appear in the textbox.

If the user changes that 3 to a 7, for example, I want that to be put back into the row, so we now have "Pencils, $5, 7"

How do I do that?

Comment: This looks very like a set up where a subform bound to the purchases table would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to program the Listbox's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and the Textbox's `TextChanged` event. Here's your snippet:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    // Exit if no item is selected
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    // Get the item's text
    Dim item As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString

    // Keep only the last part
    item = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf(", ") + 2)

    // Update the textbox
    TextBox1.Text = item

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    // Exit if no item is selected
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    // Get the item's text, removing the last part
    Dim item As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    item = item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(", ") + 2)

    // Add the numerical value of the textbox's text
    item &= Val(TextBox1.Text)

    // Get the index of the selected item
    Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex

    // Remove the old item, add the new one and select it
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(index, item)
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = index

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the item and reinsert it. You could just modify it and refresh the listbox. That will do the same.

Comment: This post is not VBA code. Neither the SelectedIndexChanged not TextChanged events exist in VBA. Please read questions more carefully before posting.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: When I replied, there was a VB.NET tag. Don't be so hasty judging other peoples' answers.

Comment: The original post also had [VBA] [MS-ACCESS] and [ACCESS-VBA]. Those are some pretty big clues that the [VB.NET] tag was out of place.